# Output list of objects in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this list of objects

```
[
{name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "description"}, 
{name: "Mary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
{name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "description"}
]
```

and I would like to print them like this divide it into two columns and desc below them. Clicking on each name displays some description below the list.

```
Dan 25       Tom 18 
Mary 15
**descripton pop up**
```

I tried this

```
var test = [    
{name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "description"}, 
{name: "Mary", age: 15, desc: "description"}, 
{name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "description"}
]
document.write(test[0].name, test[0].age + "<br>",
 test[1].name, test[1].age+ "<br>",
 test[2].name, test[2].age+ "<br>");
```

but I need to sort them alphabetically and really don't know how to print description value below them when user clicks on name, using JavaScript or jQuery.

Can you guys please help me! I'm stuck her and new in all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/KKYZj/5/

JS:

$(function() {

```
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            $('.main').append("<a onclick='javascript:details(\"" + data[i].name + "\")'>" + data[i].name + " " + data[i].age + "</a></br>");
        }
        else
        {
            $('.sidebar').append("<a onclick='javascript:details(\"" + data[i].name + "\")'>" + data[i].name + " " + data[i].age + "</a></br>");
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [
            {name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "test"}, 
            {name: "Mary", age: 15, desc: "description"},
            {name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "haaha"}
        ];

        function findName(personName){
            return $.grep(data, function(item){
              return item.name == personName;
            });
        }

        function details(personName)
        {
            var person = findName(personName.toString())[0];
            $('#description').html(person.desc);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class='main'>
        </div>
        <div class='sidebar'>
        </div>
        <div id="description">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS(proof of concept):

```
.main {
float:left;
width:250px;
background:#9c9;
}
.sidebar {
float:right;
width:250px;
background:#c9c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This is exactly what I need. I was in depression all day because of this! :) Thank you!

Comment: Can you please tell me if I want to add third column how can I do that? I tried "else if" but... :( DEMO [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KKYZj/5/)

Comment: absolutely, however past 2 columns it gets harder to keep using css without using bootstrap (twitter bootstrap an awesome css library).  If you are willing to use that i'll submit another DEMO with that usage.

Answer (score 0):

Output:

```
var output = "<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Desc</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  output += "<tr><td>" + persons[i].name + "</td><td>" + persons[i].age + "</td><td>" + persons[i].desc + "</td></tr>";
}
output += "</tbody></table>";
```

For the description:

```
"<td onclick='alert(\"" + persons[i].desc + "\")'>" + persons[i].name + "</td>"
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dSnjj/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to this.

To display the list:
You can define a function that will write the list out like so:

```
function displayPerson(person) {

  var $person = $('#persons').append('<div class="person">'+person.name+' '+person.age+'</div>')
  $person.data('description', person.desc);
  $person.on('click',function(e){
    $('#description').html($(this).data('description'))
  })
}
```

Then you can all the function with any list sorted however you want

```
var test = [    
  {name: "Dan", age: 25, desc: "description"}, 
  {name: "Mary", age: 15, desc: "description"}, 
  {name: "Tom", age: 18, desc: "description"}
]

(function(){
  test = test.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.name > b.name;
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    displayPerson(test[i]);
  }
});
```

Then just have a general html structure like so

```
<div id='persons'></div>
<div id='description'></div>
```

That should produce the html needed with click events to display the descriptions

http://jsfiddle.net/YDvkA/

Comment: Thank you Jason for quick reply and great explanation!